# jquery ajax method not triggering on remote server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

Firstly, all my works on php,mysql and js were on local server.For the first time i am putting my work online.But i have encountered some problems doing so.

I have a post-answer section on my web page where i use jquery ajax to submit a form containing users answer.This functionality working fine on my local machine but when ***i attempt to submit it online under my domain which is ezphp.tk*** , i get the following error:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of
>   the JSON data
>
> ...tion(b){if(a.JSON&&a.JSON.parse)return a.JSON.parse(b+"");var
>   c,d=null,e=m.trim(...

my ajax method is the following :

```
$.ajax('../includes/verifycomment.php',{
    data   :{
        'comment_body'     :$(this).val(),
        'userpost_post_id' : <?php echo $postid;?>,
        'users_user_id'    : <?php echo $userdata->user_id; ?>,
        'answers_answer_id':$(this).data('id')
    },
    datatype:'json',
    method  :'POST',
    success :function(response){
    var obj=$.parseJSON(response);

       if(obj['text']){
          alert(obj['text']);
          $(textarea[i]).val('');
          $(textarea[i]).hide();
          $(comment[i]).show();
          return false;

       }else{
          $(textarea[i]).val('');
          $(textarea[i]).hide();
          var obj=$.parseJSON(response);

          var str="<div class='stylecomment' >"+obj[0]['comment_body']+" --- <span style='color:#d3d3d3;font-size:13px;'>   commented by </span><a href='../includes/profile.php?user=<?php echo escape($userdata->username);?>'><?php echo escape($userdata->username);?></a> </div></div>";
          $(cmntholder[i]).append(str);
          $(comment[i]).show();
        }
    }


});
```

my response :

[image]

Comment: Please post your `response`.

Comment: You probably have error in php show us the response you get from the server.

Comment: you mean the content on var obj=$.parseJSON(response); the value of obj variable ?

Comment: No, response from the server, content of response variable. Add console.log(response) or check the response in network tab in developer tools.

Comment: will console.log work on a php page ?

Comment: If it's javascript, then yes it will work.

Comment: i have added an image of my response..console.log not working ..so i had to alert it

Comment: alert on local host prints the output of image..but on server it says [object object]

Answer (score 0):

$(this) is referring to the ajax, create variables outside the ajax function with the values, correct datatype to dataType remove parsing of oject and return, use preventDefault to stop default click action, append url attribute to the ajax object

Try:

```
 var cbody = $(this).val(),answ = $(this).data('id');

     $.ajax({url:'../includes/verifycomment.php',
                data :{
                    'comment_body'     :cbody,
                    'userpost_post_id' : '<?php echo $postid;?>',
                    'users_user_id'    : '<?php echo $userdata->user_id; ?>',
                    'answers_answer_id':answ
                },
                dataType:'json',
                method  :'POST',
                success :function(response){
                var obj=response;

                   if(obj['text']){
                      alert(obj['text']);
                      $(textarea[i]).val('');
                      $(textarea[i]).hide();
                      $(comment[i]).show();

                   }else{
                      $(textarea[i]).val('');
                      $(textarea[i]).hide();
                      var obj=response;

                      var str="<div class='stylecomment' >"+obj[0]['comment_body']+" --- <span style='color:#d3d3d3;font-size:13px;'>   commented by </span><a href='../includes/profile.php?user=<?php echo escape($userdata->username);?>'><?php echo escape($userdata->username);?></a> </div></div>";
                      $(cmntholder[i]).append(str);
                      $(comment[i]).show();
                    }
                }


            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this:

```
 var obj=$.parseJSON(response);
```

As you already have `dataType:"json"` so you don't need to parse it again.

Comment: but working on local pc...why it will create problem on remote server ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `"datatype:'json',"` with `"dataType:'json',"`
Example

```
             $.ajax('../includes/verifycomment.php',{
                data   :{
                    'comment_body'     :$(this).val(),
                    'userpost_post_id' : <?php echo $postid;?>,
                    'users_user_id'    : <?php echo $userdata->user_id; ?>,
                    'answers_answer_id':$(this).data('id')
                },
                dataType:'json',
                method  :'POST',
                success :function(response){
                if(response.text){
                     //handle success
                }else{
                     //handle error
                }

            });
```

UPDATE :

```
 $.ajax('../includes/verifycomment.php',{
                    data   :{
                        'comment_body'     :$(this).val(),
                        'userpost_post_id' : <?php echo $postid;?>,
                        'users_user_id'    : <?php echo $userdata->user_id; ?>,
                        'answers_answer_id':$(this).data('id')
                    },
                    dataType:'json',
                    method  :'POST',
                    success :function(response){
                    if(response!=""){
                       var _array=JSON.parse(response);
                     alert("Answer id is "+_array[0].answer_id);

                     }else{
                         //handle error
                    alert("Response is empty");
                    }

                });
```

For more details refer http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: what "datatype:'json'." .. i have found nothing similar to that line in my code

Comment: "t" in your datatype is small case and mine dataType "T" is capital case.

Comment: i have changed that.but sitll same..i alerted the response form server.On localhost it prints the response similar to the image i added to my post.But on remote server it prints [object object]

Comment: i unfortunately deleated your comment while deleating mine..:(..with capital "T" both local and remote server prints [object object]. what i should do now? why it is not json ?  as i set the dataType to json

Comment: you changed $.parseJSON to JSON.parse.. those two are similar i guess ??i am getting the same error

Comment: Instead of returning JSON array as response, you can return it as JSON object.